# Idiom about forgetting about someone/something

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

Someone provides something that only caters to half the group - what's an idiom for what he did to the other half by forgetting about them?

Let them go to the dogs? Something like that...

Comment: [Let them eat cake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_them_eat_cake).

Comment: [**Let them eat cake**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/let-them-eat-cake) - *used for talking about the attitude of someone who really does not care about a group of people or does not understand their problems although they pretend to*.

Comment: @MicahWindsor: Snap! **Sod the rest!** (of the suggestions! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers XD

Comment: @MicahWindsor, although I didn't think to include it in my answer (you and I were writing at the same time, I think), I do like _let them eat cake_. I tend to think of this as something said by the person doing the ignoring, but I suppose a third party could also use it to describe something that someone else did.

Comment: @IsabelArcher You can thank (allegedly) Marie Antoinette for that one.

Comment: @MicahWindsor, "Qu'ils mangent de la brioche".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is *treated them like [chopped liver](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chopped%20liver)*. This is a widely used idiom, indicating that he treated them as though they were insignificant.

Another idiom could be *[wrote them off](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/write+off)*.

If the omission was really grave and could lead to serious consequences, one choice could be *[hung them out to dry](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hang+out+to+dry)*.

More "standard" [possibilities](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/to-ignore-something-or-to-not-pay-attention) might include:

- *showed no regard for* them or *disregarded* them
- *did not take them into consideration* or *did not consider* them
- *overlooked* them
- *left them out*
- *ignored* them

As always, of course, context should determine your choice.

Comment: Treated them like *chopped liver*. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Your question**: Someone provides something that only caters to half the group - what's an idiom for what he did to the other half by forgetting about them?

Perhaps he **gave short shrift** or **didn't give a second thought** to half the group. From the idiom component of The Free Dictionary:

> **[give short shrift](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+short+shrift)**: To ignore, disregard, or exclude (someone or something); to give (someone or something) very little time or attention.
>
> **[not give (something) a second thought](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/don%27t+give+it+a+second+thought)**: To not give some situation or decision pause for any hesitation, concern, or further consideration.